# Join Keyed tables in a list

Tags: kdb

I've got a list of keyed tables:

```
ktbls:(([filter: `a`b] user1: 3 4f);([filter: `a`c] user2: 3 4f);([filter: `$()] user3: "f"$()))
```

I want to join the tables by column, so I want to run this: `ktbls[0],'ktbls[1],'ktbls[2]` which results in the keyed table below:

```
filter|user1 user2 user3
  a   |  3     3    0n       
  b   |  4     0n   0n
  c   |  0n    4    0n
```

Now since the length of the keyed table list can vary I need to somehow functionalise: `ktbls[0],'ktbls[1],'ktbls[2],'...`
However, I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your syntax:

```
q){x,'y}/[ktbls]   / alternate forms ,'/[ktbls] or (,')/[ktbls]
filter| user1 user2 user3
------| -----------------
a     | 3     3
b     | 4
c     |       4
```

But perhaps union join (`uj`) could work too?

```
q)(uj/)ktbls
filter| user1 user2 user3
------| -----------------
a     | 3     3
b     | 4
c     |       4
```

Alternative syntax `uj/[ktbls]`.

See the [documentation](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#binary-values) on this use case of over `/`.